# Jenkins class TransientBuildActionFactory how to use?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I meet a question when writing a jenkins plugin. I want to use TransientBuildActionFactory to add my plugin action to the job's build, but I can't find any demo code to use this class.
Could anyone show me a example for how to use it?

I learn TransientBuildActionFactory infomation from this : [jenkins wiki about it](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Action+and+its+family+of+subtypes)

> More recently, we are introducing a series of Transient***ActionFactory, such as TransientViewActionFactory, so that transient actions can be contributed without implementing another stateful extension point like Builder. We hope to add such extension points for more host types.

Thanks

Comment: I find that in the Jenkins WIKI

Answer (score 1):

`TransientBuildActionFactory` had been deprecated as stated in the [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/TransientBuildActionFactory.html). It's replaced with `TransientActionFactory`.

The example can be found at [JobConfigHistoryActionFactory.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jobConfigHistory-plugin/blob/jobConfigHistory-2.10/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/jobConfigHistory/JobConfigHistoryActionFactory.java)